# date manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I have this string for example `"November 8, 2016 - December 7, 2016"` which I want to extract the two dates in the this format: **YYYY-MM-DD**.
Now, I managed to get the dates in the format I want in the following way:

**HTML:**

`<span id="selecDate">November 8, 2016 - December 7, 2016</span>`

**Javascript:**

```
date = $('#selecDate').text().split('-');
begin = new Date(date[1]);
begin = begin.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

The problem is that `date = ["November 8, 2016 ", " December 7, 2016"]`

and `begin = "Wed Dec 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST)"`

when in second line but in the last line the value of begin changes to `"2016-12-06"`, one day earlier. Any idea how can I avoid it?

I'm working from *(GMT+02:00) time zone*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute `toISOString()` the date you get back is in UTC time so it takes the time back 2 hours (because of your current timezone). Midnight on Dec 06 in IST is 22:00 in UTC time the day before.

If you wish to keep your timestamps in local time, you can use a `.toLocaleDateString()`, `toLocaleString()` or even just `.toString()` on your date object:

```
begin = new Date('December 7, 2016').toLocaleDateString();
```

Note that the date format is slightly different:

> a.toLocaleDateString()
> `"12/7/2016"`
>
> a.toLocaleString()
> `"12/7/2016, 12:00:00 AM"`
>
> a.toString()
> `"Wed Dec 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST)"`

Comment: None of which return the required format. Parsing of a non–ISO 8601 string is implementation dependent and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 1):

As MDN says in, method [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

> The timezone is always zero UTC offset.

And when you create your `new Date('December 7, 2016')`, what you get is:

**Wed Dec 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200**

So in UTC, the hours are subtracted by 2, giving you the day before.

**Solution**:

```
begin = begin.getFullYear() + '-' + (begin.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + begin.getDate();
```

will result in: "2016-12-07".

Answer (score 0):

```
date = ["November 8, 2016 ", " December 7, 2016"];
var b = new Date(date[1]);

//use these get methods to avoid all the confusion
var begin = b.getFullYear()+"-"+(b.getMonth()+1)+"-"+b.getDate();
console.log(_begin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not parse strings with the Date constructor, especially when they are a format other than that specified in ECMA-262 as the behaviour is implementation dependent.

If you need Date objects, you should either use a library (e.g. [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha)) and provide the format to parse or write a simple function to parse the format to a date (see below).

However, if you just want a string in a different format, just reformat the string and avoid Dates altogether:

```js
// Reformat a date string in format MMMM d, yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd
function reformatDate(s) {
  var b = s.match(/\w+/g) || [];
  var months = {jan:'01',feb:'02',mar:'03',apr:'04',may:'05',jun:'06',
                jul:'07',aug:'08',sep:'09',oct:'10',nov:'11',dec:'12'};
  return b.length == 3? b[2] + '-' + 
         months[b[0].toLowerCase().substr(0,3)] + '-' + 
         ('0' + b[1]).slice(-2) : '';
}

console.log(reformatDate('November 8, 2016'))
```

The following functions parse a date in MMMM d, yyyy format to a Date object, then format it in yyyy-mm-dd format:

```js
// Parse date string in format MMMM d, yyyy e.g. November 8, 2016
function parseDate(s) {
  var months = 'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split(' ');
  var b = s.match(/\w+/g) || [];
  var m =  months.indexOf(b[0].toLowerCase().substr(0,3));
  var d = new Date(b[2], m, b[1]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == m? d : new Date(NaN);
}

function toISODate(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + z(d.getDate());
}

console.log(toISODate(parseDate('November 8, 2016')))
```

Using a library like moment.js you'd do:

```js
'November 8, 2016 - December 7, 2016'.split(' - ').forEach(function(s) {
   var d = moment(s,'MMMM D, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   console.log(d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```